# ValueError: too many values to unpack python while reading list

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
    materialCheck = []
    materialCheck.append(str(data['material']))
    materialCheck.append(str(data['kind']))
    dct = dict((key, tuple(v for (k, v) in pairs))
        for (key, pairs) in itertools.groupby(materialCheck, lambda pair: pair[0]))
    print dct
```

I am trying to append data to list and trying to make some thing like this
{1: ('A', 'B'), 2: ('C')}

Comment: How does your `data` look like?

Comment: And how dies pairs look like ?

Comment: materialCheck=[('1111','U'),('1111','D'),('1111','U+'),('222','U')]         Its a huge list generating dynamically..I am trying to change the list to {1111: ('U', 'D','UP+'), 222: ('u')}...It throws an error ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: and what is `pairs`? Its difficult to say whats happening, without complete information.

Comment: The pairs look like this [('1111','U'),('1111','D'),('1111','U+'),('222','U')] they are around 30,000 pairs with Different numbers and Version would be repeating like U / D / U+  I am trying to make the above list like this {1111: ('U', 'D','UP+'), 222: ('u')}..Hope u got some Idea Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your code is doing, but you could do what you want as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

materialCheck=[('1111','U'),('1111','D'),('1111','U+'),('222','U')] 

a_dict = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in materialCheck:
    a_dict[k] += v

print(a_dict)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'1111': ['U', 'D', 'U', '+'], '222': ['U']})
```

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement(converting a list of tuples to a dictionary), you can do something like the following(without importing any libraries such as collections, itertools, etc)

```
materialCheck=[('1111','U'),('1111','D'),('1111','U+'),('222','U')]
output_dict = {}
for item in materialCheck:
    if item[0] not in output_dict:
        output_dict[item[0]] = []
    output_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])
```

This will do.

If you want this to be done your way, the error is with the line `dct = dict((key, tuple(v for (k, v) in pairs))`. This should work for you:

```
materialCheck = []
materialCheck.append(str(data['material']))
materialCheck.append(str(data['kind']))
dct = {}
for (key, pairs) in itertools.groupby(materialCheck, lambda pair: pair[0]):
    dct[key] = tuple(v for (k, v) in pairs)
print dct
```

The ValueError is possible if the `data['material']` or `data['kind']` is not a two value list. The required input would be like this:

```
data = {'material' : [('1111', 'U'), ('222', 'U')], 'kind' : [('1111', 'D'), ('1111', 'U+')]}
```